# Select2 with Backbone.Marionette: Pre-selected values not hidden

Tags: javascript, marionette, jquery-select2, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am trying to integrate Select2 within a Marionette ItemView.

The problem: I want to initialize the Select2 with already-selected values, but the selected elements are still available in the dropdown. If I clear the box then manually reselect the items from the dropdown, the items are then properly removed from the dropdown.

Javascript:

```
View.Profile = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: profileTpl,
    onShow: function(){
      var $select = this.$("#categories"); // grabs the element for Select2
      $select.select2();                   // build the Select2 element
      $select.select2("val", ["american", "french", "italian"]); // select values
    }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="categories" data-placeholder="Add a category..." multiple class="form-control" tabindex="8">
  <option></option>
  <option value="american">American</option>
  <option value="french">French</option>
  <option value="italian">Italian</option>
  <option value="indian">Indian</option>
</select>
```

I can do this on a single html example page with no trouble.

Using Marionette's onShow, the "tag" elements correctly displayed in the Select2 box, but when I click the box to select different options, all options are still available.

I suspect there is some event not properly attached to the Select2 element because of the way I'm attaching the Select2 element in the onShow event.

Comment: i think this has todo with the initSelection, but im not sure, since its just an html page can you put together a jsfiddle to show the issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvahans/d9L6Lbwn/16/) is working example of your issue.

Just one note related to your code. It's a good practice, when accessing an element of view, use `this.$el.find('selector')` reference instead of querying it via jquery `$('selector')`.

You can do it even shorter like `this.$('selector')`.